# How to make datapump apply directly to the destination schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, migration

I have a schema on a server that returns and half I need to replicate it to another server, so I'll la and do an `expdp` on server1 sending the file to server2 and do an `impdp`. Solve the problem.

However, I wanted to know if I can not do the `expdp` and generate the file, but do an `impdp` directly on the destination without generating the file.

That would save a lot of time.

---

<sub>Original question on SoPT - [Como fazer datapump aplicar diretamente no schema destino](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187402/como-fazer-datapump-aplicar-diretamente-no-schema-destino)

*Translated by translate.google.com.*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using Network Link Import to Move Data](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-3E1D4B46-E856-4ABE-ACC5-977A898BB0F1.htm#SUTIL806)

> When the Import NETWORK_LINK parameter is used to specify a network
>   link for an import operation, SQL is used to move the data using an
>   INSERT SELECT statement. The SELECT clause retrieves the data from the
>   remote database over the network link. The INSERT clause uses SQL to
>   insert the data into the target database. **There are no dump files
>   involved.**

[NETWORK_LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-0871E56B-07EB-43B3-91DA-D1F457CF6182.htm#SUTIL919)

Comment: Very quick your response. I will read the documentation and try to apply, soon return to mark as answered, of course, if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Reading the documentation, it will not be possible, as I have `long` columns and I use some` types`. I will put it as resolved, because the technique you mentioned solves the problem in general. Thx